# Rename mysql output

Tags: mysql, rename

this may be a dumb question but how can I rename the mysql output? Like for example on the column if i select the value column like

```
SELECT val As New_Value
```

then on the output the name of that column would be New_Value right? But what if I want to rename the row? Like on the New_Value:

```
New_Value |
  Apple   |
```

Here's my code:

```
select t1.location AS Location,

  max(case when t2.locationid = '2847' then t2.value end) MR,
  max(case when t2.locationid = '2839' then t2.value end) Flow,
  max(case when t2.locationid = '2834' then t2.value end) Pressure,
  max(case when t2.locationid = '2836' then t2.value end) Level

from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1
  on t1.id = '2847'
group by t1.location
```

the output of this is

```
    Location        | MR | Flow | Pressure | Level
location/east/flow  | 20 |  25  |   34     |   45
```

this is the output i want, i just want it to be clean and I want to be able to add new text:

```
   Location  | MR | Flow | Pressure | Level
  2012 East  | 20 |  25  |   34     |   45
```

Comment: Out of curiousity. Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
SELECT CONCAT('New_', val) As New_Value
```

Be careful how you use this though, as you're going to retrieve different data than is actually in your database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean because rows have no real order unless you use a order by statement.

What I think you mean is you want to change the value of each row.

In this case, you can use CASE WHEN.

Comment: can you check out my question again? i edited it and added the code i have

Comment: Can you post the data in your table1 and 2? Without that I cannot give you an accurate answer.